# change the column orders of a stair-like data.frame in R

Tags: r

Here is a data frame with 800 rows and 9 columns.

```
             TP53                 PIK3CA  MYC    ERBB2 CCND1 MDM4 FGF3 FGF4 FGFR1
QMXZ     Missense; Missense;Missense;AMP; AMP;           AMP;                     
PDIQ Missense;DEL;              Missense;          AMP;  AMP;      AMP; AMP;      
IMOC     Missense;                                       AMP;                     
EVNQ Missense;DEL;                                 AMP;                           
ISXZ Missense;DEL;              Missense;          AMP;                           
HYBD Missense;DEL;                             Inframe;                           
QOKR     Missense; Missense;Missense;AMP;                     AMP;            AMP;
ZLPB                         Inframe;AMP;                     AMP;                
FSDZ                        Missense;AMP;                     AMP;
```

I create a plot of this data frame as shown below. Different colors represent different cell values:
[image]

I executed the following code to rearrange the columns, ensuring that columns with identical cell values are grouped together. (Using the first three columns as an example).

```
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(TP53), desc(PIK3CA), desc(MYC)) %>%
  t()
tmp_yes_no_no <- which(df['TP53', ] != '' & df['PIK3CA', ] == '' & df['MYC', ] == '')
tmp_no_yes_no <- which(df['TP53', ] == '' & df['PIK3CA', ] != '' & df['MYC', ] == '')
tmp_no_no_yes <- which(df['TP53', ] == '' & df['PIK3CA', ] == '' & df['MYC', ] != '')
tmp_yes_yes_no <- which(df['TP53', ] != '' & df['PIK3CA', ] != '' & df['MYC', ] == '')
tmp_yes_no_yes <- which(df['TP53', ] != '' & df['PIK3CA', ] == '' & df['MYC', ] != '')
tmp_no_yes_yes <- which(df['TP53', ] == '' & df['PIK3CA', ] != '' & df['MYC', ] != '')
tmp_yes_yes_yes <- which(df['TP53', ] != '' & df['PIK3CA', ] != '' & df['MYC', ] != '')
tmp_no_no_no <- which(df['TP53', ] == '' & df['PIK3CA', ] == '' & df['MYC', ] == '')
df <- df[, c(tmp_yes_yes_yes, tmp_yes_yes_no, tmp_yes_no_yes, tmp_yes_no_no, tmp_no_yes_yes, tmp_no_yes_no, tmp_no_no_yes, tmp_no_no_no)]
df
       QMXZ                     PDIQ            ISXZ            QOKR                     EVNQ            HYBD            IMOC        FSDZ            ZLPB          
TP53   "Missense;"              "Missense;DEL;" "Missense;DEL;" "Missense;"              "Missense;DEL;" "Missense;DEL;" "Missense;" ""              ""            
PIK3CA "Missense;Missense;AMP;" "Missense;"     "Missense;"     "Missense;Missense;AMP;" ""              ""              ""          "Missense;AMP;" "Inframe;AMP;"
MYC    "AMP;"                   ""              ""              ""                       ""              ""              ""          ""              ""            
ERBB2  ""                       "AMP;"          "AMP;"          ""                       "AMP;"          "Inframe;"      ""          ""              ""            
CCND1  "AMP;"                   "AMP;"          ""              ""                       ""              ""              "AMP;"      ""              ""            
MDM4   ""                       ""              ""              "AMP;"                   ""              ""              ""          "AMP;"          "AMP;"        
FGF3   ""                       "AMP;"          ""              ""                       ""              ""              ""          ""              ""            
FGF4   ""                       "AMP;"          ""              ""                       ""              ""              ""          ""              ""            
FGFR1  ""                       ""              ""              "AMP;"                   ""              ""              ""          ""              ""
```

Here is the plot after change the column order.
[image]

I'm wondering if there are any easy ways to do this for all columns to transform a large dataset into a stair-like data.frame.

Comment: Could you better describe what you mean by "stair-like"?

Comment: Are you just transposing? Perhaps try `t(df)`

Comment: @jpsmith Hi. I have edited my question.